Dynamically extending/loading a formular
i have a questionnaire like formular with (depends on configuration) 3 to n pages realized with a tab control. The instantiation is horribly slow, but thats surely caused by the control count that can easily reach 100 (f.e. 13 questions with 1 label and 7 radio buttons each) on a single page.
To speed things up i thought about creating the first page only and when the form is visible and the user is working on the first page then dynamically creating the other pages in the background.
I've tried it with a background worker on a test form and it works (i am a bit surprised lol) Can/Should controls be created on non-ui-threads? i've added a button to my test form to modify label color and text of the label created in the background worker and that works too...? Still surprised 
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
Thread.Sleep(5000);
var label = new Label();
label.BackColor = Color.Red;
label.Text = "test";
label.TextChanged += (_, _) => MessageBox.Show("Whaaaat?");
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, label);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
Label label = (Label)e.UserState;
this.Controls.Add(label);
}

Is this a good approach to reduce loading/instantiation time of forms with many many controls?

Creating controls in another tread is bad idea. To speed up form loading you can make it asynchronous: don't create/initialize ALL controls at once, rather one by one (or in small groups), giving control back to UI thread in-between. Virtualization is another possibility. Idea: load first few questions and others will be added dynamically as the user scrolls down and control bounds comes into view.

@Sinatr So instead of the background worker I use an async method that creates the other controls and await it in FormShown event?

Sure. await is optional, just make sure it is called from UI thread. You can fire-and-forget this method, therefore calling it from constructor is also an option. In the method create all the controls (in the loop?) and ensure to have await Task.Delay(1) in-between. Another option is Timer.
